# Provide a way to accept unaccepted answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, unaccepted-answer

Sometimes we provide an answer to a question, and the person who asked the question ignored it without accepting it.

For me this is not a good practice and if you asked a question you must accept the right answer. Because he is not the only one who looking for answer to the same question.  If he accepts it, it will help others with the same question.

Is there anything we can do rather than commenting?

Comment: Accepting answers is only ever up to the OP. And they shouldn't be harassed about it.

Comment: Then cant we send any reminder?? Email??

Comment: Nope. We can't and there is no need to.

Comment: Related: [Would it be possible to have a “community accepted” feature?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature)

Comment: What is it that you specifically asking to be implemented? Your "question" sounds to me like a rant about unaccepted answers but I cant really distinguish what the actual feature is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-in

Comment: There is no *requirement* that anyone accept an answer here, and never has been. This has been discussed here several times before. There is also no requirement to leave a comment when you downvote (or upvote) a question and no requirement to comment when voting to close. It's also inappropriate to nag a user to accept your answer (or anyone else's, for that matter) by commenting, emailing, or any other means.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is nothing you can do other than leaving a polite comment - but even then this may well be counter productive.

If the user is a new user then they might not know how the site works - in this case a polite comment might be useful.

If the user knows how the system works then even a comment would be counter productive and could be seen as badgering the user. Such comments will probably be removed by moderators should they been seen.

Only the question asker can accept an answer.

This has been raised before:

[Would it be possible to have a "community accepted" feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature)

and declined.

Answer (score 4):

I believe there are cases where the OP just isn't aware of the custom to accept a correct answer. Posting a polite comment reminding the OP of this seems like good practice to me. It educates new users for which they may actually be thankful. I healthy accept rate will motivate others to answer their questions in the future.

A better solution may be to have the system remind the OP of this custom after posting the question.

Comment: Yes. Reminder it is. Good point.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think the system already does issue reminders.

Comment: Honestly, I wasn't sure..

Comment: i didn't get any yet.